# Cut and Paste All columns if cell a particular equals "Fri" in a Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to develop a VBA Macro to Cut and Paste All columns if cell a particular equals "Fri" in a range. It should paste all cut columns after the last empty column.

Can you please help me with this. Please note that the range will change according to the Days in a month.

### Thanks in Advance!

Original

01   02   03  04  05  06  07  08  09

Thu  Fri  Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri

Result

01   03  04  05  06  07  08  |02   09

### Thu  Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu |Fri  Fri

Comment: Sorry i couldnt attach the image

Comment: Please show us your source code, you don't need to attach an image

Comment: I am not a developer. Can you give me a sample code with which i can study further

Comment: I have added sample text.

Comment: you can start by recording the macros go to view tab -> Macros -> Record Macros, once you finish recording your actions, you will be able to examine the code generated by the macro

Comment: I have done it. But I need to automate it. Excel should search for "Fri" text on row no.5

Comment: Sub Macro1()
Columns("Q:Q").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("AR:AR").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("W:W").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("AR:AR").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("AD:AD").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("AS:AS").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("AK:AK").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("AT:AT").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("W:W").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("AC:AC").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
  Columns("AI:AI").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("AN16").Select
End Sub